# how to disable/enable after/previous options from a drop-down menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

Maybe my question is not clear, but this is what I looking for:

When I select an area from my *svg* (in my case, a *polygon*) from a d*rop-down menu list*, the area appears orange, then when I select another area from my *drop-down menu list*, the next area appears orange but the previous one does not disappears.. why? I would like to select just one selected, not both.

Many Thanks

info:

1. "*sel1*" is the id of my *drop-down menu*
2. "*polygon*" is my area of my *svg*

```js
// start connection between svg and drop down menu

// selection the "polygon" that affect the "select"
$(".map-image").on('click', function(evt) {
  // Get the id of the region we clicked on
  var regionId = evt.target.id;
  // Update the dropdown
  $('#sel1 option').removeAttr('selected')
    .filter('[value=' + regionId + ']')
    .attr('selected', true);
  // Highlight the relevant region
  setRegion(regionId);
});

// select from the menu and have the color on the svg
$("#sel1").change(function(evt) {
  //console.log($(this).val());
  var name_region = ($(this).val());
  var regions = $(document).find('#' + name_region).get(0);
  //console.log(regions);
  $(regions).css('fill', '#FF7409');
});



function onRectClick(evt) {
  // Get the id of the region we clicked on
  var regionId = evt.target.id;
  // Update the dropdown
  $("#sel1").val(regionId).change();
  // Highlight the relevant region
  setRegion(regionId);
}


function onSelectChange() {
  // Get selected class from dropdown
  var selectedRegion = $("#sel1").val();
  // Highlight the relevant region
  setRegion(selectedRegion);
}

function setRegion(regionId) {
  // Remove "selected" class from current region
  $(".region.selected").removeClass("selected");
  // Add "selected" class to new region
  $('polygon#' + regionId).addClass("selected");
  $('polygon#').find('map-title').css('display', 'block');


  // Note: for addClass() etc to work on SVGs, you need jQuery 3+
}


// Init map based on default select value
//onSelectChange();
// done connection between svg and drop down menu
});
```

```css
polygon.selected {
  fill: #ff7409;
}
```

```html
<!-- drop down menu -->
<label for="sel1">Seleziona Area:</label>
<select class="form-control" id="sel1">
  <option value="region1">1 - Udine Centro</option>
  <option value="region2">2 - Rizzi / S. Domenico / Cormor / S. Rocco</option> 
  <option value="region3">3 - Laipacco / San Gottardo</option>
  <option value="region4">4 - Udine sud</option>
  <option value="region5">5 - Cussignacco</option>
  <option value="region6">6 - S. Paolo / S. Osvaldo</option>
  <option value="region7">7 - Chiavris / Paderno</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You have two /select and you are missing an onload - there is something missing from the beginning

Comment: onload? what do you mean? sorry I'm a newbie. Thanks.

Comment: $(function() {....

Comment: Your snippet is reporting a syntax error.  Which is probably why your code is not functioning properlyl.  Open your browser dev tools (F12). Any Javascript errors will be shown in the Console.

Comment: Ok thanks I will check. If anyone wants, can you send me a new code for this? In case, I will not find the error. Thanks!

Comment: Guys... I dont know where the error is.. if you want please, help me. Thanks

Comment: I have added 
$("polygon").click(onRectClick);
    $("#sel1").change(onSelectChange);

on the top of my code.. but nothing happen...

Comment: anyone can help? :(